# Compile apache ignite c++ examples

Tags: c++, ignite

I want to use apache ignite along a c++ application I am developing. So far, I've downloaded ignite from the website, and compiled the ignite c++ as specified in the DEVNOTES.TXT file:

```
cd platforms/cpp
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoreconf
./configure
make
```

It seems to work, since I got no error messages. However, I couldn't found binaries for the example applications, such as the code in the  putget-example directory, which is close to what I want to do in my own code.

Thus, I'd like to know how can I compile this and other ignite c++ examples. Also, suppose I want to use apache ignite with another application I'm writing, how do I compile it with ignite c++ library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples should be compiled separately. See `platforms/cpp/examples/README.txt`:

```
cd platforms/cpp/examples
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoreconf
./configure
make
```

Note, that you have to compile main project prior to building examples (which you've already done, I believe).